# Retrieve flight information from email

Tags: email, parsing

How would I parse an email and extract flight reservation details (if it exists)?

I'm only looking to parse Gmail emails right now, so if it specifically uses the Gmail API, that's okay.

Though I had a look at the Gmail API (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get), and tried the API on a specific message from my inbox that contains the flight reservation popup on the webapp, and couldn't find anything flight-related in the API.

So how would I do that in the generic case? By parsing directly the email body? Is there a library for that?

Thanks.

Comment: Extremely doubtful you can find a package to do this. Instead, expect to be writing string parsing functions for each unique domain (e.g. website) and message format (you'll have to test a lot) to search for and extract that information. Perhaps some of it can be generalized for keyword searching, after you figure out how to programmatically access emails from gmail (I'm sure there is an API for that).

Comment: Hi, did you manage to do that?